# Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, where $n \geq 3$. Suppose that $\Delta(G) \geq n/2$. Can $G$ have more than one component?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices, where $n \geq 3$. Suppose that $\Delta(G) \geq n/2$. Can $G$ have more than one component?
i did this for $n=3$ $\Delta(G) \geq 1.5$ as $\Delta.1$ component.
for $n=4 \Delta(G)\geq2$ as $|=|$ like square.again $1$ component.
So my answer to this question is $G$ can not have more than one component.
What do you think?

Comment: The notation $\Delta(G)$ usually denotes the **maximum** degree of a vertex in the graph $G.$ Is that what you mean??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $G$ can have multiple components.

Assuming $\Delta(G)$ does indeed represent the maximum degree (or even if it somehow means average degree), then consider the disjoint union of a $K_{n-2}$ with a $K_2$.  The average degree will be $(n-2)(n-3)+2 > \frac{n}{2}$ and the maximum degree will be $n-3>\frac{n}{2}$ for large enough $n$.